# Passport.js not calling LocalStrategy if fields are empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm having a problem where if I try to login with no username or password my `passport.use` function isn't being called at all.

Below is my express post route that runs `passport.authenticate`.

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        failureRedirect: '/login', // redirect back to the login page if there is an error
        failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
    })
```

And below is my `passport.use` that should print `GOT HERE` whenever there is a post request to `/login`.

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        console.log("GOT HERE");
```

This works fine if `email` and `password` have some type of value. But I would like this function to be called even if there is no value for `email` and `password` so that I can do custom error handling.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add middleware befure authentication strategy being called. Something like this:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    // do custom error handling
  }, passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        failureRedirect: '/login', // redirect back to the login page if there is an error
        failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
})
```

And in this middleware you could do some custom error handling

Comment: Is that really the best way to do it? Currently all of my error handling is in the passport function. So separating it seems unintuitive.

Comment: You can find from source code here: 
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/f82655aa220ad7d0fcd8b114a0303d3cf94b8d06/lib/strategy.js#L71
First thing that `authenticate` function do is check if there is passowrd and username field. So I would say that is the easiest way.

Comment: @CharlieFish that's how `passport-local` works. If you want custom behaviour, you can use a strategy like [`passport-custom`](https://github.com/mbell8903/passport-custom).

Comment: Thanks @robertklep and @ IvanVasiljevic